# I want to find a word (actually an adjective) that describes an event which is now occurring

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Is there an adjective to describe an event which is being occurred now? for example, a football game that is being played now, a conference that is being held now and so on.

Comment: Current? Ongoing?

Comment: **current** [synonyms:](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/current) *contemporary, present-day, **present,** contemporaneous, **ongoing,** topical, in the news, **live,** alive, happening, burning, modern, latest, popular, fashionable, in fashion, in vogue, up to date, up to the minute*. That wasn't particularly difficult "research".

Comment: I see this all this as a 'work in progress'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could be described as an *ongoing* event.

> **ongoing** |ˈɒnɡəʊɪŋ| adjective
>
> continuing; still in progress: *ongoing negotiations*.

Answer (score 0):

It may seem obvious, but nothing fits your description better than **live**